# Test iOS app as it was in Asia

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, network-programming

I've got this issue,

I have an ios app stored on App Store, and it is working well when is downloaded in South America. But when is downloaded in Asia, especially China, it does not work properly (The connection is down and some packages are lost, so that I cannot syncronized the app. The main host is in Colombia and The app in China maybe the are many network hops).

I make unit and functional test before the release and all goes well on our environment.

Somebody knows if it is possible testing and simulating and app as it was in China.

Update : I believe that maybe the host is far away I have tried with this pages, however I can't Identify the real problem.

1. https://tools.keycdn.com/ping
2. http://www.maplatency.com/
3. http://www.super-ping.com/

Comment: Does your app have any functionality depending upon the location of user? And what do you mean by **not work properly**? Provide more details on it.

Comment: Is the actual location a problem or does the use of chinese characters and chinese number / currency / etc. formatting cause issues?

Comment: @PrerakSola  I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have a way to do it from Xcode, run it on a device and while the app is running select a location and it will simulate that location

[image]